# Return false only first ul ( exclude children links ) in navigation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, navigation, nav

I'm currently working on a navigation and have run into some trouble. It has a fixed nav, with a slideToggle menu for children of the navigation. I need to have the "li" with a class of "parent" return false so it doesn't jump back to the top of the page when clicked. However, when I do this it disables all the children links. Is it possible to just target the parent itself and return just that one false?

HTML:

```
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li class="parent">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

JS:

```
$("li.parent").click(function(){
   $(this).children("ul").slideToggle(300);
   return false;
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/first/

Comment: Fix your code. You have open tags and li elements outside ul. Either post your complete code. And don't put nav or other unknown  elements.

Comment: @JimmyKane it isn't unknown http://html5-webdesign.de/nav.html

Comment: Yes you are correct @algorhythm . Sorry I am not full aware of the all the new things of html5.

Comment: use 'javascript:void();' instead of '#' for the hrefs, because the '#'-link can make problems with ajax in relation with an ipad ;-)

Comment: I still don't exactly know the problem. I tried to create a jsfiddle to recreate the problem http://jsfiddle.net/qF6Gf/ but I don't know where to go from there. I removed the `<a></a>` tags as you can just click directly on the div to show/hide the submenu. Are you saying the `<a></a>` tags cause the page to reload? If that is the case, algorhythm's method should work imo.

Comment: Sorry about the typos, they are fixed. You can see the menu here: http://beta.revival.tv/ The problem is if you are scrolled down on the page and click it, it jumps back to the top before the page is loaded. If I return it false then the links just collapse the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution by using and if statement and .preventDefault()

The following code is what I ended up with

```
$("li.parent").click(function(e){
  if($(this).children("ul").is(':hidden')) {
      e.preventDefault();
  };
  $(this).children("ul").first().slideToggle(300);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try it with `eq(0)` to match only the first occurrence of the `<ul>`s

```
$("li.parent").click(function(){
    $(this).children("ul").eq(0).slideToggle(300);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I tried this with no luck. If you click on the links of that ul they are still returning false as well. I just need to return the ul as false.